# Modify a very precise line of a php file

Tags: php, file

Good morning,

I am creating a configuration file in php to manage the variables of my website.

I would like, thanks to a php script, to be able to modify a specific line of my configuration file.

I tried this code:

```
$file_content = file('manager/libs/config.php');
$file_content[11] = "ligne changée";

$fh = fopen('manager/libs/config.php', 'r+');
foreach($file_content as $line)
{
  fputs($fh, $line."\r");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Unfortunately, he writes well to the line concerned (line 12), but he moves all the other lines. It’s hard to explain because I don’t understand exactly what he’s doing...

**Here is my request**: Have a php script allowing me to modify a very precise line of my configuration file without interfering with the others.

I have done a lot of research on this but no script is suitable for my use...

Comment: A hint: always google your problem before posting it. It will save you the typing of the entire question

Comment: for the configuration files you should REALLY use var_export()